# Change the database in Microstrategy Intelligent Cube

Tags: report, cube, microstrategy

How to change the database of an already created Intelligent Cube in Microstrategy?

I have a cube which is getting data from Tables in production.
We have same tables in other database as well.
Is there any way i can modify the cube to use the new database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify just your cube to point to a different database if it was not create as a FFSQL report (in that case it's easy, you just change the database instance used), but you have a couple of options:

1. Modify the database connection setting for the database instance used by your project. My suggestion is to create a new database connection for the other database and point the current instance to this new connection
2. Create a new database instance (if you don't have it already) and assign it as default one to your project. Not sure it the existing tables will be mapped to the new one automatically.
3. Create a new database instance (like above), open the Warehouse catalog and change the database instance for the tables used in the cube.

Sincerely I would go for the first option if the other database contains all the tables required by your project.